# Foreigner crossing the Canada/ U.S border by car

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paris, borders, romance

My boyfriend is from France and I am from Michigan, he is coming in July to visit with me and my family but we are flying into Toronto and from Toronto we are crossing the U.S border by car. Would there be a problem at the border with him not being  Canadian or a U.S citizen? As in...can he cross the border by car if he is not from either country?

Comment: For the most part, a border crossing is a border crossing is a border crossing. Is all of his paperwork in order? If he'd be able to fly in directly, crossing overland should be no different.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect there'd be a problem?[